# Change padding when toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written this code

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.input_search').hide();

    $(".search").click(function () {
        $(this).css("padding", "0 0 0 130px");
        $(this).css("background", "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)");
        $(this).find("a").css("display", "none");

        $(".input_search").show();
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    display: table-cell;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin: 0 2px;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="search">
        <a href="#" title="Search">Search</a>
        <input type="text" class="input_search" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is when I click on `.search`, its padding moves to the left smoothly (with slideToggle instead of click() ).
And I want that the input displays in the li at the left.

My code is incomplete and I'm stuck here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

just add this css in your css file.

```
.search{
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

this is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L361sjhc/1/)

i think thats it you want [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L361sjhc/6/)

Comment: Simple, neat and hardware-accelerated. +1

Comment: I want to close the li too. How can you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
      $('.input_search').hide();

      $(".search").on('click', function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).children('a').show();
              $(this).removeClass('open');
              $(".input_search").hide();
              
            } else {
              $(this).children('a').hide();
              $(this).addClass('open');
              $(".input_search").show();
              
            }
          });

      });
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  font-size: 18px;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.search {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.search.open {
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 80px;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="search">
    <a href="#" title="Search">Search</a>
    <input type="text" class="input_search" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Corentin Branquet...looking for something like this?

Comment: When you click on the input, the li is closing .

Comment: I add a link close next to input for closing, how can you apply this in this code ?